# New to Python and wondering why a is not defined in the error

Tags: python

This is my first python program after taking a C class this summer and I'm wondering why a is not defined in the errors I'm getting, I thought we didn't have to declare in Python. What is wrong with my program in general?

Code:

```
def is_right(a, b, c):
    a=int(raw_input())
    b=int(raw_input())
    c=int(raw_input())

    if (a**2)*(b**2)==c**2:
        print 'Right'
    elif (b**2)*(c**2)==a**2:
        print 'Right'
    elif (c**2)*(a**2)==b**2:
        print 'Right'
    else:
        print 'Not Right'

def main():
    is_right(a, b, c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why does `is_right()` even have three parameters when you then immediately replace them with `raw_input()` results? You get a name error because **in `main()`** the names `a`, `b` and `c` are not defined.

Comment: put the raw_inputs in the `def main()` function, not in the `is_right` function.

Comment: You don't have to *declare* variables, but that doesn't mean you can use *uninitialized* variables.

Comment: You would have the same error if you did this in C.

Comment: Python.org has a reasonably good tutorial. You should work your way through it.

Answer (score 1):

In the main function, where you make the function call to is_right, a, b and c are variables that haven't been defined. When calling that function either you can pass the raw values as arguments or define a, b and c before the function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_right(a, b, c):

    if (a**2)*(b**2)==c**2:
        print 'Right'
    elif (b**2)*(c**2)==a**2:
        print 'Right'
    elif (c**2)*(a**2)==b**2:
        print 'Right'
    else:
        print 'Not Right'

def main():
    a=int(raw_input())
    b=int(raw_input())
    c=int(raw_input())
    is_right(a, b, c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```